# Need research topic for below requirement in Sentiment analysis and opinion mining

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I want to do sentiment analysis for few approaches such as politics, entertainment, business(product review) using few APIs such as Twitter, facebook, youtube. For this I need a research topic. Can you suggest a research topic for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing a project with sentiment analysis, there's a lot of things where you can use it like market projections or social topics. For example, to make online evaluations of an MVP to select the final features of a new product or to predict election result by analyzing tweets.